# Let V be an inner product space. Prove that for every $u,v\in V: (u,v)=\frac{1}{4}\left(||u+v||^{2}-||u-v||^{2}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space.
Prove that for every $u,v\in V$:
$(u,v)=\frac{1}{4}\left(||u+v||^{2}-||u-v||^{2}\right)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425173/derivation-of-the-polarization-identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $$|u+v|^2=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle$$

Now expand this inner product...

Do you now see what is $|u-v|^2$??

Can you complete now??

Comment: so (u,v)= 1/4((u+v,u+v)-(u-v,u-v)) ?

Comment: do you know what is $\langle a+b ,c\rangle$??

Comment: so(a+b,c)=(a,c)+(a,b) ?

Comment: very good.. Now what is $\langle u+v,u+v\rangle$?

Comment: ok i see, so is it (u,u+v)+(v,u+v) ? and then expand this like (a+b,c)

Comment: yes... what would be final answer?

Comment: (u,u)+(u,v)+(v,u)+(v,v)= (u,u)+2(u,v)+(v,v)

Comment: very good.. so, now you have $\langle u+v,u+v\rangle =(u,u)+(u,v)+(v,u)+(v,v)$ similarly calculate $(u-v,u-v)$ and subtract....

Comment: ah i see, think ive got it now, thanks very much

Comment: Make sure you have really got it... Let me see what you have got...

Comment: so (u+v,u+v)-(u-v,u-v)=(u,u)+2(u,v)+(v,v)-(u,u)+2(u,v)-(v,v)=4(u,v)

Comment: that is it... if you are sure that you have got you answer... you better accept some answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$||u\pm v||^2=||u||^2\pm2(u,v)+||v||^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Rough Analogy:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\\(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\\ab=\frac14[(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2]$$

---

$$(\vec a+\vec b)^2=a^2+b^2+2(a,b)\\(\vec a-\vec b)^2=a^2+b^2-2(a,b)\\(a,b)=\frac14[(\vec a+\vec b)^2-(\vec a-\vec b)^2]$$

Comment: so 1/4(|u+v|^2-|u-v|^2) once expanded cancels down to equal uv ?

Comment: @Daleboy24 yes, see the edit