# On the proof of $\langle T(v),v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V \iff T(v)=0$ for all $v \in V $

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For a complex inner product space $V$ and a linear map $T:V \to V$
$$\langle T(v),v \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } v \in V \iff T(v)=0 \text{ for all } v \in V $$

One proof makes use of the identity

$$ \begin{align}
\langle T(u),w \rangle  = &  \frac{\langle T(u+w),u+w \rangle - \langle T(u-w),u-w \rangle}{4} \\
&+ \frac{\langle T(u+iw),u+iw \rangle - \langle T(u-iw),u-iw \rangle}{4}i
\end{align}$$

and observing each term on the right is of the form $\langle T(v),v \rangle$.

Where does the above identity come from? Is there an easy way to see it is true? Are there any proofs that don't rely on this identity?

I verified the identity by expanding the RHS but didn't recieve any insight.

---

**Reference**

Axler, S. (2015). Linear Algebra Done Right. (Third ed.). Theorem 7.14 (p. 210). New York: Springer

Comment: "Is there an easy way to see it is true?" Yes. Just the way you chose - expanding the RHS.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I suppose I don't really want an easy way, but rather a less tedious and more insightful way. Something in the spirit of Euler's four squares identity with quaternions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity is the complex [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for those interested in derivations see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425173/derivation-of-the-polarization-identities/506643#506643