# On the proof of that the only linear operator mapping each element of a complex vector space to an orthogonal element is the $0$ operator

Tags: linear-algebra

In the proof from Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler uses the following equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Tu,w \rangle  =   \frac{\langle T(u+w),u+w \rangle - \langle T(u-w),u-w \rangle}{4} \
&+ \frac{\langle T(u+iw),u+iw \rangle - \langle T(u-iw),u-iw \rangle}{4}i
\end{align}
$$
to rearrange $\langle Tu, w\rangle$ to a sum of $\langle Tv,v\rangle$ forms. I read from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720788/on-the-proof-of-langle-tv-v-rangle-0-for-all-v-in-v-iff-tv-0-for-a) link and one answer suggests that the identity above is the polarization identity. However, although the $\frac{1}{4}$ coefficient resembles, I cannot see how the above sum of inner products is the same as the polarization identity, which represent the inner product on the left hand side as a sum of norms. My question is: is the above identity really essentially the polarization identity? If not, what is the motif behind the identity (what motivates it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the polarization identity for the bilinear form
$$
B(u,w)=\langle Tu,w\rangle.
$$
The identity that you mention is a particular case when $T=Id$. In general, the identity relates the bilinear form to the corresponding quadratic form.

The polarization identity is invoked whenever you want to conclude something about the dot product (angles, etc.) based on information about lengths. For example, you can prove that a linear transformation preserving lengths also preserves angles, areas, etc.