# Prove $\langle u,v \rangle =\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4} i^k\|u+i^kv\|^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. prove that for all $u,v \in \mathbb{V}$, $\langle u,v \rangle =\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4} i^k\|u+i^kv\|^2$.

My attempt:
$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4i^k\|u+i^kv\|^2=\frac{1}{4}(i\|u+iv\|^2-\|u-v\|^2-i\|u-iv\|^2+\|u+v\|^2)=\frac{1}{4}(i\langle u+iv,u+iv\rangle-\langle u-v,u-v\rangle-i\langle u-iv,u-iv\rangle+\langle u+v,u+v \rangle)=\frac{1}{4}(i\langle u,u\rangle+i\langle u,iv\rangle+i\langle iv,u\rangle+i\langle iv,iv \rangle-\langle u,u\rangle...=\langle u,v \rangle$.

Wow, who came up with that? Is there a name for this?
Is there alternate proof?

Comment: This is a *polarisation identity*. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_complex_scalars. You may also like to read this page: [Derivation of the polarization identities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425173/derivation-of-the-polarization-identities)

Comment: AH ok! thank you!