# Obtaining the underlying bilinear form from a Hermitian form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

According to Evar Nering's "Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory", 2nd edition, (12.4 on page 172; full text here: https://archive.org/details/LinearAlgebraAndMatrixTheory/page/n4), the underlying bilinear form of a Hermitian quadratic form can be obtained by the following:

$f(a, b) = 1/4[q(a + b) - q(a - b) - iq(a + ib) + iq(a - ib)]$

where f is the bilinear form, $q$ is a Hermitian form, a and b are any two vectors, and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Can anyone please explain how this relationship can be derived or be shown to be true? (A similar relationship for quadratic forms is derived in 9.1 on page 161 of the text. I'm having problems applying the same reasoning to the case above.)

Thank you.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a variation on the polarization identity.

Comment: @amd Thanks--that's great. A derivation is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425173/derivation-of-the-polarization-identities
The relationship can be verified by substituting f(a + b, a + b) for q(a + b), etc., and then expanding the functions on the r.h.s., and summing the resulting terms.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer. MSE imposes a delay before you can post answers to your own question, but off the top of my head I don’t remember what it is.