# A complex Banach space satisfying the parallelogram law is Hilbert

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $H$ be a Banach space with associated norm $\|-\|.$ Suppose that for any $x,y\in H,$ we have:
$$\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\left(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\right),$$
which we call the parallelogram law.
Then it is a well-known standard fact that $H$ becomes a Hilbert space. This is true both for real and complex coefficients.

I managed to prove this fact for an Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R},$ 
 defining the inner product 
$$(x,y) \mapsto \langle x,y\rangle=\frac{\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2}{4}= \frac{\|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2}{2}.$$

**Question**

> How to prove this for the complex case?

The inner product should be in this case 
$$(x,y)\mapsto\ \alpha(x,y)= \frac{1}{4} \left(\|x + y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2 + i\|x + iy\|^2 -i\|x-iy\|^2 \right)=  \langle x,y \rangle + i \langle x,iy \rangle$$
but I am not able to replicate the proof of the real case.

> It would be awesome if there was a slick proof that used the real case to deduce the complex case, but I would still be happy with any kind of direct proof too. Since this is a standard result, if you can provide a reference where a detailed proof is given, that would be excellent too.

Comment: @MatheusNunes Mmh, I'm not seeing how

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I think that what you want is here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/506643/523585

Comment: @MatheusNunes I don't see how: that question is about deriving the polarization identities once you know you have an inner product; my question is on how to prove that using them you get an inner product.

Comment: I copied the wrong link. Sorry https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43848/523585

Comment: @MatheusNunes yeah that may be what I'm looking for; it treats the real case and then says something about the complex case too. thank you!

Comment: To your recent edit: Note if you can show $$c\alpha(x,y) = \alpha(cx,y)$$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then in light of the distributive property and what you've already shown, it suffices to just show it for $c=i$.  This should be straightforward to do.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Maybe I'm stupid, but $i\alpha(x,y)=\alpha(ix,y)$ does not seem straightforward at all; and neither $\alpha(x,y)=\overline{\alpha(y,x)}$

Comment: To start, I'd write out the definitions of $\alpha(ix,y)$ and $\overline{\alpha(y,x)}.$  Then for both, you just factor out an $i$ when needed.  For instance, $$\|ix+y\|^2 = \|i(x-iy)\|^2 = |i|^2\|x-iy\|^2 = \|x-iy\|^2.$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring yeah, I tried that. But I end up in messy calculations that don't get me anywhere.

Comment: @marialami: Recall the inner product $\langle . , .\rangle$ in your post is defined when considering $H$ as *real* vector space. So, factoring out complex numbers like $i$ is not admissible.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer of course! I feel so dumb. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|: H\to \mathbb{R}$ be a norm in a complex Banach space $H$ which fulfills for all $x,y\in H$ the parallelogram law
\begin{align*}
\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\left(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We show the map $\alpha:H\times H\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
 \alpha(x,y)= \frac{1}{4} \left\{\|x + y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2 + i\|x + iy\|^2 -i\|x-iy\|^2 \right\}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
fulfills for all $x,y,z  \in  H$  and $c\in\mathbb{C}$
\begin{align*}
c\alpha(x,y)=\alpha(cx,y)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Let $x,y,z\in H$. We have
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\alpha(x,y)+\alpha(z,y)}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\left\{\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.+\|z+y\|^2-\|z-y\|^2+i\|z+iy\|^2-i\|z-iy\|^2\right\}\tag{4}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1}{4}\left\{
> \left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}+y\right)+\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2+\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}+y\right)-\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.-\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}-y\right)+\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2+\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}-y\right)-\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+i\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}+iy\right)+\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2+i\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}+iy\right)-\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.-i\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}-iy\right)+\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2+i\left\|\left(\frac{x+z}{2}-iy\right)-\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\right\}\tag{5}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\left\|\frac{x+z}{2}+y\right\|^2+\left\|\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2
> -\left\|\frac{x+z}{2}-y\right\|^2-\left\|\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.+i\left\|\frac{x+z}{2}+iy\right\|^2+i\left\|\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2
> -i\left\|\frac{x+z}{2}-iy\right\|^2-i\left\|\frac{x-z}{2}\right\|^2\right\}\tag{6}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=2\alpha\left(\frac{x+z}{2},y\right)}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use the definition of $\alpha$ from (2).
- In (5) we do some preparatory work in order to apply the parallelogram law.
- In (6) we apply the parallelogram law (1).

> Since we have from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \alpha(x,0)&=\frac{1}{4} \left\{\|x\|^2 - \|x\|^2 + i\|x\|^2 -i\|x\|^2 \right\}=0
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain by substituting $z=0$ in (7)
>   \begin{align*}
> \alpha(x,y)=2\alpha\left(\frac{x}{2},y\right)\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain from (7) and (8) by induction that for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}_0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> 2^{-n}m\alpha(x,y)=\alpha\left(2^{-n}m x,y\right)
> \end{align*}

**Case $c\geq 0$:**

> If $c \geq 0$, then we have numbers $c_k=2^{-n(k)}m(k)$ such that $c_k\to c$ as $k\to \infty$. Since the norm $\|\cdot\|$ fulfills for all $x,y\in H$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \left|\|x\|-\|y\|\right|\leq \|x\pm y\|
> \end{align*}
>   it follows
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left|\|c_kx\pm y\|-\|cx\pm y\|\right|\leq \left|c_k-c\right|\|x\|\\
> &\left|\|ic_kx\pm y\|-\|icx\pm y\|\right|\leq \left|c_k-c\right|\|x\|\\
> \end{align*}
>   and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \alpha\left(c_kx,y\right)\to\alpha(cx,y)\qquad \text{as }k\to\infty
> \end{align*}
>   We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{c\alpha(x,y)}=\lim_{k\to\infty}c_k\alpha(x,y)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha\left(c_kx,y\right)\color{blue}{=\alpha(cx,y)}
> \end{align*}

**Case $c\in\mathbb{R}$:**

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
>  \color{blue}{\alpha(-x,y)}&=\frac{1}{4} \left\{\|-x + y\|^2 - \|-x-y\|^2 + i\|-x + iy\|^2 -i\|-x-iy\|^2 \right\}\\
>  &=-\frac{1}{4} \left\{-\|x - y\|^2 + \|x+y\|^2 - i\|x - iy\|^2 +i\|x+iy\|^2 \right\}\\
>  &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\alpha(x,y)}
> \end{align*}
>   we have $\alpha(cx,y)=c\alpha(x,y)$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case $c\in\mathbb{C}$:**

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
>  \color{blue}{\alpha(ix,y)}&=\frac{1}{4} \left\{\|ix + y\|^2 - \|ix-y\|^2 + i\|ix + iy\|^2 -i\|ix-iy\|^2 \right\}\\
>  &=\frac{i}{4} \left\{-i\|x - iy\|^2 + i\|x+iy\|^2 +\|x +y\|^2 -\|x-y\|^2 \right\}\\
>  &\,\,\color{blue}{=i\alpha(x,y)}
> \end{align*}
>   we have $\alpha(cx,y)=c\alpha(x,y)$ for all $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and the claim (3) follows.

**Note:** This post follows closely the proof provided in section 1.2 of *[Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387904271)* by J. Weidmann.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you want, see my edit.

Comment: @marialami: You're welcome.