# Is there geometric interpretation of why $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}=\frac{\lVert \vec{v}+\vec{w} \rVert^2 - \lVert \vec{v}-\vec{w} \rVert^2}{4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Is there an interesting geometric interpretation of the relationship

$$\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}=\frac{\lVert \vec{v}+\vec{w} \rVert^2 - \lVert \vec{v}-\vec{w} \rVert^2}{4}$$

Comment: In what vector space are the vectors, and what is the norm indicated by the double bars?

Comment: @coffeemath I think it's safe to assume that the norm is supposed to be the one induced by the inner product.

Comment: I solved a problem in Spivak's Calculus, asking that I prove the relationship above. It was in the appendix to a chapter on drawing Graphs, and it was the first appearance of vectors. In that appendix, the norm $\lVert v \rVert$ was defined as $\sqrt{v \cdot v}$, where $v$ is a vector.

Comment: [More on the polarization identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425173/942722). Especially [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506643/942722) answer.